# n dimensional tic tac toe finding all possible win conditions or lines in a n dimensional matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to implement an n-dimensional tic tac toe problem. To do this I want to be able to see if any player has won yet. If there is a n-dimensional matrix of n is there a way to check all the lines?

I've tried doing this in 2 dimensions and 3 dimensions but don't know how to algorithmically find all the win lines. I hope the below explains the problem in more detail.

So if we are playing 2D tic tac toe as below on a 3x3 board:

```
0 1 2     
3 4 5     
6 7 8
```

The possible lines (tic tac toe win conditions) are:
horizontal and vertical wins:

```
[0 1 2]     
[3 4 5]     
[6 7 8]     
[0 3 6]     
[1 4 7]     
[2 5 8]
```

Diagonal wins:

```
[0 4 8]     
[2 4 6]
```

If we are playing in 3 dimensions on a 4x4 board the horizontal and vertical lines are:

```
[0 1 2 3]     
[4 5 6 7]     
[ 8  9 10 11]     
[12 13 14 15]     
[ 0  4  8 12]     
[16 20 24 28]     
[32 36 40 44]     
[48 52 56 60]     
[ 0 16 32 48]     
[ 1 17 33 49]     
[ 2 18 34 50]     
[ 3 19 35 51]
```

and there are further diagonal lines (the list is non-exhaustive) i.e.:

```
[0 20 40 60]     
[0 21 42 63]
```

The first one is an edge diagonal that stays in one slice and the second is corner to corner. Things like [2 5 8] also win conditions in the 4x4 board because it is a line of length 3 on the board.

Is there a way to find all possible lines that are of length l or longer (horizontal, vertical, and diagonal) on an m-dimensional board of edge size n? n will be larger than l and m will at least be equal to 2.

I am currently using the following code to find all the horizontal and vertical cases:

```
def winEvaluation(boardInput):
     dimensions = len(boardInput.shape)

     for i in range(dimensions):
         flatMatrix = np.transpose(boardInput,np.roll(np.arange(dimensions),i)).flatten().reshape(edgeLength**(dimensions-2),edgeLength,edgeLength)
         for array in flatMatrix[0]:
           print(array)`
```

but I don't have a strong grasp of how to find all the diagonals as the dimensionality increases.

Answer (score 0):

Probably done really badly, but here's a solution. Possibly modifiable to any axbxcxd.. board size.

The key insight is that winnability is transitive: if there is a winning sequence between A and B, and B and C, so is there between A and C.

Thus we use the disjoint set structure (this implementation is somewhat memory-inefficient, maybe) and whenever you have two endpoints you take their union.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def ticTacToeWins(rowLength, dimensions):
    board = [0]
    wins = DisjSet(rowLength ** dimensions):
    for n in range(dimensions):
        winAdd = (rowLength - 1) * len(board)
        if 0 < n < rowLength:
            for i in range(1, rowLength - 1):
                for s, e in temp:
                    wins.Union(s + i * len(board), e + i * len(board))
        increment = (rowLength ** n)
        for b in board:
            wins.Union(b, winAdd + b)
        temp = wins.unionsSoFar.copy()
        new = []
        for s in range(1, rowLength):
            toAdd = s * increment
            for i in board:
                new.append(i + toAdd)
        board.extend(new)
    return wins.all_wins(rowLength)

# taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/disjoint-set-data-structures/
class DisjSet:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.rank = [1] * n
        self.parent = [i for i in range(n)]
        self.unionsSoFar = []
 
    def find(self, x):
        if (self.parent[x] != x):
            self.parent[x] = self.find(self.parent[x])
        return self.parent[x]
 
    def Union(self, x, y):
        self.unionsSoFar.append((x, y))
        xset = self.find(x)
        yset = self.find(y)
        if xset == yset:
            return
        if self.rank[xset] < self.rank[yset]:
            self.parent[xset] = yset
        elif self.rank[xset] > self.rank[yset]:
            self.parent[yset] = xset
        else:
            self.parent[yset] = xset
            self.rank[xset] = self.rank[xset] + 1

    def all_wins(self, rowLength):
        sets = defaultdict(list);
        for i, parent in enumerate(self.parent):
            sets[parent].append(i)
        print(sets)
        return [get_win(node1, node2, rowLength) for vals in sets.values() for node2 in vals for node1 in vals  if node1 < node2]
            
def get_win(start, end, rowLength):
    increment = (end - start) // (rowLength - 1)
    return [start + increment * i for i in range(rowLength)]
```